# Detect Barcode Scanner on oracle apex

Tags: javascript, oracle, oracle-apex

Detect Barcode Scanner - using Javascript 
https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=10355:32:21497051930136:::::
user     : demo
password : demo

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
 var pressed = false; 
  var chars = []; 
  $(window).keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which >= 48 && e.which <= 57) {
        chars.push(String.fromCharCode(e.which));
    }
    console.log(e.which + ":" + chars.join("|"));
    if (pressed == false) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            if (chars.length >= 10) {
                var barcode = chars.join("");
                console.log("Barcode Scanned: " + barcode);
                // assign value to some input (or do whatever you want)
                $("#P32_SCAN_BARCODE").val(barcode);
            }
            chars = [];
            pressed = false;
        },500);
      }
       pressed = true;
    });
    });
  $("#P32_SCAN_BARCODE").keypress(function(e){
  if ( e.which === 13 ) {
    console.log("Prevent form submit.");
    e.preventDefault();
   }
  });
```

Comment: Is there a question somewhere?

Comment: i am using java script to disallow keyboard input & only allow Barcode Scanner on oracle apex.

Comment: my issue has been resolved                                https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=10355:32:119889278844474:::::                           demo/demo